# Use MWPhotoBrowser without pod file

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swift2, mwphotobrowser

I was looking for a photo browser and found MWPhotoBrowser, which I really liked and wanted to add to my existing project. But in the instruction they say you have to use pod file to install MWPhotoBrowser. I dont have pod file. I want to do it without podfile. Is it possible to just drag and drop the files needed in the project and include the header in bridging file(swift project).

I searched for ways to do it, but it seems everyone do it with podfile. Detailed instructions will be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want podfile. You have to manual download and drag to your project list of dependencies below:

- [DACircularProgress](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress)
- [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)
- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
- Finally [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

Hope this help!

Comment: after following first three steps,  for MWPhotoBrowser which folder to be copied.

Comment: put folder you want, and you will face error import like: `#import <SDWebImage/SDWebImageDecoder.h>` you should edit to: `#import "SDWebImageDecoder.h"`. I think a lot error like this.

Comment: I mean which files are to be added for eg in SDWebImage there is a folder SDWebImage we drag and drop it. For MWPhotoBrowser which folder to be selected.

Comment: All file in Core Folder of SDImage

Comment: I am talking about MWPhotoBrowser https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser which files to add.

Comment: All file in Classes and Assets

Comment: So copy the folder Classes and assets to a folder named MWPhotoBrowser and add the MWPhotoBrowser folder to the project. is this right? then how to add it to bridging file

Comment: How to add it to bridging file? I know this asking lot of question but i am new to this area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97584/discussion-between-vien-vu-and-user2413621).

Answer (score -4):

its better to use pod.
to install pod hit following command in terminal

- sudo gem install cocoapods

than navigate you project in terminal .following code in terminal

- pod init

you will see now the is pod file in yout project.open pod file and follow the instruction given in mwphotobrowser.

hope this will help you.

Comment: OP specifically said `I want to do it without podfile`.